# TweetSharp - Where did FluentTwitter go?

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp, twitterizer

In TweetSharp 1.0 there was FluentTwitter, TweetSharp 2.0 doesn't seem to have this anywhere, it doesn't even seem to be deprecated but rather just deleted altogether, can anyone point me if this part of TweetSharp is still available in 2.0 and how to access it?

In their google code page, they even have topics talking about FluentTwitter, like [this one](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FluentVsService), which isn't navigable (you can't reach it apparently) but it shows up in google search results. I don't really know what Dimebrain is, is this a custom version of TweetSharp, or just how v1.0 was named, or what?

Really confusing.

Something similar happens with Twitterizer, they claim on their site that you should only need Twitterizer2.dll and Newtonsoft.Json.dll for most projects, but that you could also use stuff like Twitterizer2.Streaming.dll, which is nowhere to be found...

> Twitterizer2.Streaming.dll
>   This is
>   an addon library that provides access
>   to the Streaming API.
>   This file is
>   not necessary for most projects.

I need a Twitter API wrapper that is up-to-date and allows using the Streaming API.

**Update** Where can I download a working copy of [this version](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/Network-Clients/TweetSharp/TweetSharp/CatalogTweetSharp.htm) of TweetSharp? I downloaded that version file by file creating my own solution and providing the reference libraries I thought it needed, but I just keep hitting walls and walls of compile-time errors..

**Update** Twitterizer seems to not support the Streaming API, that's why they don't include their streaming wrapper library in their main release. Still no clue about TweetSharp though.

**Update** TweetSharp also seems to have jumped non-stop in repositories: google search yields results in all of the following: `google code`, [github](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp), `codeplex`, and [nuget](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/TweetSharp), yet `google code` and `codeplex` links seem to have been removed.

Comment: It appears to be supported here: http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FluentVsService

Comment: @0A0D That's exactly what my question states?

Comment: I just don't see how it is deleted, as you state in your first sentence.

Comment: Have you tried downloading TweetSharp 2.0.6 or 2.0.3? It just isn't there. I have no clue why either.

Comment: This doesn't answer the primary question, but Twitterizer.Streaming.dll is distributed separately. And it's true, for most projects, the two dlls you mentioned will be the only needed, that's why they are put together in a release and the others are elsewhere on the downloads page.

Comment: For the record, TweetSharp is no longer in development. It says so on its GitHub home page, where it moved to in June from CodePlex. (Not sure who the crazed downvoter is, because I upvoted.)

Comment: @BoltClock yet if you read this... http://www.twitterizer.net/480/im-still-here/ , they have been known to come back after "officially quitting"

Comment: @Nico: Well that was last year, and from someone else's POV. It seems TweetSharp is being put to rest for good this time.

Comment: I have had the same question few days ago - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705087/where-is-tweetsharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best option for now (2012) is to move to [Twitterizer](http://nuget.org/packages/twitterizer/).

[Twitterizer Streaming API Public Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895304/twitterizer-streaming-api-public-stream)

```
using Twitterizer.Streaming 
// ...
```

Nice tutorial: 
http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2011/11/29/twitter-real-time-search/

Answer (score 4):

To answer your primary question: TweetSharp dropped its fluent style API in the release of 2.0. Furthermore, TweetSharp is no longer maintained by its authors, this is why finding information about it, outside of its github repository, is problematic.

In the past I've released a very early beta prototype of twitterizer's streaming binary as a separate download (in the 'addons' release). The most recent version, however, contains the streaming binary that is fully working and stable (at least for the user stream).

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you view cached pages to uncover more info via google.  You said that the data at that page wasn't accessible, but it is:
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:RWqwl4mpcOMJ:tweetsharp.codeplex.com/wikipage%3Ftitle%3DFluentVsService+fluenttwitter&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=jp&source=www.google.co.jp

Also, you should use google's advanced search feature to get more info.  Rather than 'should include one of the following words', use 'must include', or type a + before your term.  +fluenttwitter gave me a page with code that uses the .dll file you're trying to use in FluentTwatter 2.  Lol, oops.  I mean FluentTwitter.  You may be able to use google in this same way to find whatever dll file you are looking for, but I would be worried about virii.  I used it to find drive files, like this: +sidewinder_joystick_driver32.dll.  It also helped me to find missing system files and doom2.wad + dwango. ;D

Finally, there's this: http://pm.twitterizer.net/projects/twitterizer-stream.  It confirms that Twitterizer doesn't support a streaming API, but these people are after the same thing.  It's always refreshing to find people working towards the same goal.  If you are stuck in the middle of something, they might have the next step.  Maybe they'll give you SVN access to some working draft, and you will be able to use it under a special developer's license of some kind! :D

Best of luck to you!

Comment: I meant you couldn't navigate the codeplex page and reach that page "naturally" just by browsing, rather than google searching for it. Like they forgot to delete it, but it wasn't meant to be there.

Comment: I agree.  I also checked with some c# people and some TweetSharp, and there seems to be no plan of moving forward with the streaming project anytime soon.  So, I think it's going to be a long wait, at best.  On the other hand, there's a better possibility that they are looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

At this point (2017) TweetSharp has all but dropped off the face of the earth. All of the original Github repos are straight up deleted making them almost impossible to find. This is a real problem when you inherit a legacy project and need to maintain it, since you can't get the source anymore...

A new author is maintaining it here now and it seems to be a drop-in replacement thus far.

https://github.com/Yortw/tweetmoasharp