# Where is TweetSharp?

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

Cannot find TweetSharp v2.0

http://tweetsharp.com/ is expired

http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/ - 404

http://code.google.com/p/tweetsharp/ - 403

https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp/ - seems out of date, for example does not have TweetSharp.Twitter.dll

This is quite strange. May be some light on this?

Comment: I wonder if they pulled the project when Twitter changed their API rules?

Comment: Last answer states that it is something connected with money.

Comment: It's been moved to GitHub: https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp . This move hasn't been publicized at all though. Main developers http://stackoverflow.com/users/18440/daniel-crenna and http://stackoverflow.com/users/2187/jason-diller are probably the only ones who could shed light on the motives.

Comment: I wrote it. Yes, it's on my github now. It's still open source, always has been. It's not connected to money, I just don't want to work on it anymore for free, so you can either take the code and do whatever you want from it, or pay for updates. If other people pay for updates (which they have), I update the library with new changes. No big conspiracy, I just moved on. I have 25 OSS projects, I'm bored of this one at the moment.

Comment: @DanielCrenna It's not on your GitHub anymore and it's nearly impossible to find. For those looking for a compatible replacement (or source code) see https://github.com/Yortw/tweetmoasharp

Comment: @jocull https://github.com/danielcrenna/vault

Comment: why is this closed? mods are you not smart enough?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would say this is a case of Non [Responsible Open Source Code Parenting.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/12/responsible-open-source-code-parenting.html)
Read this: [I am still here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130131142401/http://www.twitterizer.net:80/480/im-still-here/)

---

Bottomline is, IMHO, **do not use it**.

Comment: @Mike: i dont even know those guys. but read the last but one comment by the tweetsharp guy. he has given his twitter handle. even thats deleted. :) so...

Comment: It has been moved to GitHub: https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp . The project seems to have had a hectic lifecycle, agree with naveen's conclusion.

Comment: It's just code. You can do what you want with it. It's MIT-licensed. It's here - https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp. Use whatever you want. It just became too hard to support a steady stream of people asking for help so I stopped. The companies that use it and pay for updates are happy with it. You might be happier with something else.

Comment: the `I am still here` link is a 404. rather ironic

Comment: Everything he had on Github has been removed, which was super rude. You can find the new maintainer here: https://github.com/Yortw/tweetmoasharp

Comment: @jocull I moved all old code to https://github.com/danielcrenna/vault, but yes please use your link in the future

Answer (score 1):

There is still a [NuGet package](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/TweetSharp) available, but I'd be wary of using it given that the Codeplex/Google code/Twitter accounts all appear to have been deleted recently.

Answer (score 1):

Here: http://nuget.org/List/Packages/TweetSharp

Comment: But this is not source code. And project link is expired GoDaddy domain. I have this dll from hundreds of other libs that uses TweetSharp

Comment: Well, I guess it's gone for good. I wonder why...