# MVC, C# - TweetSharp - Post with logged in user

Tags: c#, authentication, model-view-controller, twitter, tweetsharp

This is looks very simple, but not workis for me.
The user is logged in to my application and to twitter too.

The exception is:
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

```
 var twitterStatus = twitterService.SendTweet(new SendTweetOptions() { Status = message });
```

maybe I have to use this too ?
    twitterService.AuthenticateWith(_accessToken, _accessTokenSecret);

but how can I get the logged in user's accestoken and accesstoken security for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Tweetsharp is not longer beeing maintained. I have used it myself in the past but I was forced to switch. Now I use Linq2Twitter. There are ways to fix this but I have not tried this since it is no longer being developed.

Comment: Make sure to also visit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705087/where-is-tweetsharp?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
twitterService.AuthenticateWith(_accessToken, _accessTokenSecret); is working is I add directly MY accessToken and AccessTokenSecret, just I don't know how can I use the actually authenticated user's AccessToken and AccessTokenSecret.

Comment: And what can I use if not Tweetsharp ? Linq2Twitter ?

Comment: Of all the .Net libraries for Twitter implementation I like Linq2Twitter the best although it works a bit different doing Async calls etc. Still the documentation is allright.