# Twitterizer Streaming API Public Stream

Tags: c#, twitterizer

I have been trying to get the public status message using the Twitterizer streaming API but unable to perform. I used the code below but it doesn't work. The sample code only provide user stream method works but not for public stream. My code below:-

```
stream.StartPublicStream(streamErrorCallBack, tweetCreated, deletedCallBack, eventCallBack);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve but if you have a look at http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/tag/json/ you will find a complete public stream example.